# How to convert an IEnumerable<AnonymousType> to a List<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable, anonymous-types

I've filtered down a `List<Application>` using Linq to concatenate two fields within that list and return a result, and now need to return that list to the calling method.

The result from the Linq filtering is of type `IEnumerable<AnonymousType>` so I can't return that as is my method return type is `List<Application>`.

What I did try at first is to convert the IEnumerable using the ToList method but that throws a compiler error:

```
IEnumerable does not contain a definition for ToList()
```

**Question:**

How can I convert or cast an IEnumerable to a List ?

**Code:**

This the assignment carried out on the List to concatenate two fields and return it as a list:

```
                var filteredAppList = applicationList.Select(c => new { c.RID, RID_APP_FIELD = c.RID + " " + c.BusinessFriendlyName });
```

And below is how I try to return the IEnumerable  as a List:

```
                return filteredAppList.ToList<Application>();
```

Comment: Why are you trying to convert back to Application class?

Comment: None of your objects *are* `Application` objects. They are instances of an anonymous type. To do what you want essentially involves doing `.Select(x => new Application { RID = x.RID, ...})` etc - either manually or automated; why are you switching to an anonymous type if you want `Application` instances?

Comment: Is `RID_APP_FIELD` a property in `Application`? If not you either have to make it one or override `ToString` in this way: `return RID + " " + BusinessFriendlyName`. Then you don't need to create new instances but you can return `applicationList.Where(conditions).ToList()`

Comment: `RID_APP_FIELD` is the anonymous type created from concatenating both RID and BusinessFriendlyName. @TimSchmelter

Comment: @BrianJ: No, it's not the anonymous type but one of it's properties. That's why i've asked. If you need to return a `List<Application>` but you want to provide this property you have to modify the class in the way i've shown above.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ok my mistake so I need to create an anonymous property RID_APP_FIELD  in the Application model class?

Comment: @BrianJ: no, you can't have anonymous properties in concrete classes. Either add a property like: `public string RID_APP_FIELD {
            get { return RID + " " + BusinessFriendlyName; }
        }` or override `ToString` in this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

problem is, previous query returns a sequence of *anonymous* objects, we are trying converting these to `Application` type. Which is causing the issue, Try this.

```
filteredAppList.Select(x=> new Application() 
                          {
                              // set properties.

                          })
               .ToList();
```

Comment: I need to return the list formatted as "RID + BusinessFriendlyName" so the resulting filtered list would be like : "879898 TestAppOne" etc..  Can you give more detail on how to set the properties above?

Comment: How do you define `Application` class? You need to set Application properties here.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you need to return `Application` objects you should simply avoid the anonymous type:

```
var filteredAppList = applicationList.Select(c => new Application { RID = c.RID, RID_APP_FIELD = c.RID + " " + c.BusinessFriendlyName });

return filteredAppList.ToList();
```

I assumed that your anonymous type was strictly identical to your `Application` type, but that might not be the case. You can still use anonymous types in intermediary steps, but the runtime will hardly be able to automatically convert your anonymous type to `Application`, so projecting back to an instance of the desired type is pretty much your only option.

```
var filteredAppList = applicationList.Select(c => new { RID = c.RID, RID_APP_FIELD = c.RID + " " + c.BusinessFriendlyName });

return filteredAppList.Select(anon => new Application { RID = anon.RID, OtherApplicationProperty = anon.RID_APP_FIELD }).ToList();
```